# problem with bibtex-I want to check format

Tags: bibtex, errors

I just want to know if the following reference is written in the correct format of a `.bib` file. The error I got when compiling it is

```
Warning--empty journal in saleh_medina_leila_m._structural_2014
Warning--empty year in saleh_medina_leila_m._structural_2014
```

the entry is

```
@article{saleh_medina_leila_m._structural_2014,
    title = {Structural, dielectric and magnetic properties of Bi1-{xYxFeO}3 (0 {\textless}x {\textless} 0.2) obtained by acid–base co-precipitation},
    volume = {592},
    doi = {10.1016/j.jallcom.2013.12.243},
    pages = {306--312},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Alloys and Compounds},
    shortjournal = {J. Alloys. Comp.},
    author = {{Saleh Medina, Leila M.} and {Jorge, Guillermo} and {Negri, R. Martín}},
    date = {2014}
}
```

Comment: Your `.bib` file looks as if it was written for `biblatex`. If you use it with standard BibTeX styles, you need to use the `year` field and not `date`, also `journaltitle` needs to be `journal`. Finally, your `author` field should be `author = {Saleh Medina, Leila M. and Jorge, Guillermo and Negri, R. Martín},`, i.e. don't double brace authors as this will treat the name as one unit and does not distinguish between first and last names.

Comment: the `date` field need to have an argument with following format : `yyyy-mm-dd` (cf. http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf p.14)

Comment: @ebo But it is OK to leave out information you don't have, so `date = {2014}` if you only have the year is perfectly fine, you can even have `date = {2014-12}` for December 2014.

Comment: @moewe I didn't knew, thanks for information.

Comment: @moewe I imported the .bib file from Zotero Standalone. I tried to compile it with BibLatex, without success. is there a way not to write the .bib to solve this? thanks!

Comment: Can you show a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of the document you try to use this with?

Comment: @moewe here I sent an MWE (I hope it's complete, I am novice) \documentclass[serif,mathserif,final]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{lankton}}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,pxfonts,eulervm,xspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./figures/}}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=custom,width=84,height=119,scale=1.2,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
 \begin{document} \begin{block}{Preparaci\'on de las pel\'iculas} Las $BiFeO_{3}$  sintetizadas \cite{saleh_medina_leila_m._structural_2014} y tolueno.\end{block}\end{document}

Comment: While it is not exactly complete the MWE suggest that you are not uzsing the package `biblatex`, but the `cite` package and thus "normal" BibTeX where the restrictions I explained above apply. You have to use `year` and not `date`, and `journal` instead of `journaltitle`. `shortjournal` will probably be ignored. Or you switch to use `biblatex` ([What to do to switch to biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864))